# Is Sarima(0,0,0)(5,0,0,12) the same as the 5 year avg of a given month?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima

Trying to understand big P,D,Q in sarima better. Could probably ask a broader question to get more info but my first question is making sure I understand at least the seasonal AR term.

With m=12 (monthly data), say the month being forecast is May, would Sarima(0,0,0)(5,0,0) just return the average of the value for May the past 5 years?

Answer (score 0):

Your SARIMA model above should not be said to simply return the *moving average* of the (May monthly) values for the past 5 years, instead it has a seasonal autoregressive component via using the past 5 values of the time series at a frequency of 12 to make a forecast for the next value. Its specific forecast result would form a weighted linear combination of those 5 values and the weights are dependent on the characteristic of your sample time series dataset being fit to. Finally keep in mind in time series modeling the [moving average process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving-average_model) is conceptually different from moving average proper as emphasized in the reference:

> The moving-average model should not be confused with the moving average, a distinct concept despite some similarities. Contrary to the AR model, the finite MA model is always stationary... The moving-average model is essentially a finite impulse response filter applied to white noise, with some additional interpretation placed on it... in the MA model a shock affects $X$ values only for the current period and $q$ periods into the future; in contrast, in the AR model a shock affects $X$ values infinitely far into the future

Comment: The last sentence is incorrect. The model has a seasonal autoregressive component, and that *cannot* be the same as a simple moving average, exponential smoothing or "other" autoregressive forms. Also, when you say "it uses the past 5 values of the series at a frequency of 12", this actually *does* mean the last five May months on record. It is not an average of these values, though, but a (weighted) linear combination.

Comment: @RichardHardy thanks for your comment! I've corrected per your suggestion.